# AngularJS: separate create/edit page from manage page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I have single page application and three pages: ManageList, CreateList, EditList
I use one controller for it and two views (manageView and CreateEditView)

```
when('/manageList', {
    templateUrl: settings.baseurl + '/app/modules/sample/list-partial.html',
    controller: 'listController',
    resolve: {
        listName: '$route',


        function ($route) {
            return {
                editList: false,
                manageList: true;

            }
        }]
}
}).
when('/createManageList', {
    templateUrl: settings.baseurl + '/app/modules/sample/createEdit-partial.html',
    controller: 'listController'
},
resolve: {
    listName: '$route',


    function ($route) {
        return {
            editList: false,
            manageList: false;

        }
    }]
}
}).
when('/editList/listName/:listName', {
    templateUrl: settings.baseurl + '/app/modules/sample/createEdit-partial.html',
    controller: 'listController',
    resolve: {
        listName: '$route',


        function ($route) {
            return {
                editList: $route.current.params.listName,
                manageList: false;

            }
        }]
}
}).
```

In listController I manage what code to be executed by listName and manageList params

```
if (listName.editList) {
    //code for editing goes here
} else if (listName.manageList) {
    //code for managing goes here

} else {
    // code for creating goes here 
}
```

The question: is there a better way to separate logic for create page. I don't really like this evil if else.

Comment: Just use seperate controllers for each view.

Comment: why do not use three controllers for your three pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create 3 controllers, (one for each view) .
If you have some common behaviours, you may create a service or a factory, declare inside the features and inject it into all needed controllers.

A controller must be tiny, you shouldn't declare all your code logic inside them.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about it. Looks like it's the only one way to solve this problem.